# Customize UITableView background color

Tags: iphone, uitableview, colors, background

The problem is quite simple but is pretty annoying. I put a groupe style UITableView in a view controller and make the controller the table view's delegate and datasource.

When I what to change the color of the background of the table, I use:

```
UIColor *backColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(15.0 / 255.0) green:(170.0 / 255.0) blue:(230.0 / 255.0) alpha: 0.75f];

[self.myTable setBackgroundColor:backColor];
```

and in `tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath` method, I just return a simple cell:

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];    
if (cell == nil){
cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
 reuseIdentifier:moreCellIdentifier] autorelease];
}

cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
return cell;
```

But the strange thing is that at the round corner of each cell the color is just not right, and I think it's because the frame of one of the subviews of the cell is larger then the cell and I tried to make the frames of subviews small but still failed.Any idea?Thanks.

Comment: I think this is the problem with the width of the cells, I subclass UITableViewCell and make the new cell class of width only 200, but in table view the cell still take almost entire width of screen.

Answer (score 0):

Try with using the below code in your  `tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath` function.

```
   NSString *CellIdentifier = [[NSString  alloc] initWithFormat:@"CellIdentifier_%d_%d",indexPath.section,indexPath.row];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];    
    if (cell == nil){
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
     reuseIdentifier:moreCellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    [CellIdentifier  release];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
    return cell;
```

Comment: These codes just change the way to assign cell identifier to a cell, and it has nothing to do with the problem I met here.

Comment: @Jhaliya: Yes, and it doesn't work. I figure out this is the problem with the width of the cells, I subclass UITableViewCell and make the new cell class of width only 200, but in table view the cell still take almost entire width of screen.

Comment: @joe522 :you could debug it by giving the backgroung color to you cell and see the area occupied them.

Comment: @Jhaliya: good idea. I tried to fill one of the subviews of cell with color each time I run my app, and I find that it's the content view of the cell is out of the bound of cell

Comment: @Jhaliya: any idea to decrease the size of conten view and make it smaller than the frame of the cell? I tried setBound and setFrame, both do not work here.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, it is not clear to me what this line:

```
[self.myTable setBackgroundColor:backColor];
```

refers to. What is myTable? and what is self?

Anyway, if you are using a `UITableViewController` to manage your table, you should change the background color like this:

```
UIColor *backColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(15.0 / 255.0) green:(170.0 / 255.0) blue:(230.0 / 255.0) alpha: 0.75f];
tableViewController.tableView.backgroundColor = backColor;
```

If you subclass `UITableViewController`, the best place where to execute that code is `viewWillAppear` (using self instead of tableViewController.tableView.backgroundColor).